# Populating source IP address in a raw socket to get a valid response

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, raw-sockets

I am doing some basic network programming using c/c++. What I am trying to do is create packets with headers populated with my own values (instead of kernel) , send packet to some server and get a response. I was able to create the tcp/ip header structures and populate fields such as seq_num etc . As an example, I would send a SYN packet to a host at some port, and check if the host responds with a valid SYN_ACK.

I am wondering what needs to be put in for the source_address and source_port field in the ip/tcp header so that I get a valid response. Using local address (127.0.0.1) won't work right, cause the target machine won't be able to send a response.

I have to use raw_sockets only, can't use SOCK_STREAM etc. Using Linux OS.

Comment: I think you'd send an IP address of a network interface you are listening on. The IP must be valid from the point of view of the remote site.

Answer (score 1):

The source IP address should be the ip address of interface from which you expect the packet to go out to reach the destination. To make things less complicated the source port can be any free port on your machine.

Also you need to take care of one more thing. Once you get the syn-ack back it will be also handled by the tcp stack of your machine and tcp stack will send a reset in response to that syn-ack. If you are on linux you can use iptables to drop the out going reset.

-MS

Comment: Yes for receiving as well i will be using raw sockets. I can figure that out. What I could come up with was : 1) For the source_ip use the ifaddr structures and info from those. 2) For the port just do a get getpid() % 65535 ( a little buggy, but okay for now). Will this work ?

Comment: I think it will be better to directly use a port number from ephemeral port range directly as using this formula may give to port number 0 and sometimes may give a port number from 1-1024.

Comment: yes, thats why I said "a little buggy". another way i thought of was using clock time to calculate a random number. I can figure this out. So is the ifaddr approach correct for getting source_ip?

Comment: Yes, the reason to use the outgoing interface's ip address is because you want response back to you. For e.g if you give a source Ip of google then the packets will go to google's server and not your box. Main point is that other side should know how to reach the source IP you are using.